# css code how to put the navigation in the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a webpage,in which the screen  will fit into the mobile also.

**style.css**

```
/* GENERAL STUFF */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

/*.clear {
    clear: both;
}*/

.clear:after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
}

/* HEADER BLOCK */

.header-background {

    padding-top: 50px;
}

 .header-background > div:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    background: #232323;
} 

.header {
    background: #232323;
    color: #B2B2B2;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

.header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.header a:active {
    color: #19A3A3;
}






#nav {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    margin: 0;
    background: #333;

    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#nav, #nav * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

.nav-item {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* Desktop */

#desktop-nav .nav-item {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: right;

    -webkit-transition: color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: color 200ms linear;
    transition: color 200ms linear;
}

#desktop-nav .nav-item:hover, #desktop-nav .nav-item:active {
    opacity: 0.7;
}


/* Mobile */

#mobile-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: visibility 0ms linear 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0ms linear 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: visibility 0ms linear 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: visibility 0ms linear 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;
    transition: visibility 0ms linear 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;
}

#mobile-nav .nav-item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    background: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: background 200ms linear, color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background 200ms linear, color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background 200ms linear, color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: background 200ms linear, color 200ms linear;
    transition: background 200ms linear, color 200ms linear;
}

#mobile-nav .nav-item:hover, #mobile-nav .nav-item:active {
    background: #666;
    color: white;
}

#mobile-nav .nav-item:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}


/* Toggles */

.nav-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 0px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    margin: 16px 22px;

    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('../images/menu-icon.svg');
    background-color: #333;
}

.nav-toggle:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#open-toggle:focus {
    left: -100px;
}

#open-toggle:focus ~ #close-toggle {
    left: auto;
}

#open-toggle:focus ~ #mobile-nav {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

#open-toggle:focus ~ #mobile-nav .nav-item {
    opacity: 1; /* Avoid initial fade in of content, have to use opacity because using visibility breaks functionality */
}


/* Logo */

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff
}

#logo:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}




















.header-logo {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding: 8px;
    float: left;
}

.header-notes {
    padding: 100px 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}

.header-notes div {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
}

span.green {
    color: #19A3A3;
}

/* PAGE MAIN CONTENT */

.content {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.content h2 {
    color: #19A3A3;
    padding: 25px;
}

.content p {
    padding: 25px 15%;
}

.hr-background {
    background: url(../img/hr-bg.png);
    width: 229px;
    height: 14px;
    margin: auto;
}

.photos {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
}

.photos ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 1%;
    width: 23%;
}

.photos ul li img {
    width: 100%;
}

.photos ul li:hover h3 {
    color: #19A3A3;
}

.photos a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.photos h3 {
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.photos p {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0;
}

.slider {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 60px;
}

.slider ul {
    height: 8px;
}

.slider ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    background: url(../img/slide_point_bg.png) no-repeat;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.slider ul li.active {
    background: url(../img/slide_point_active_bg.png) no-repeat;
}

.slider ul li:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em black;
}

/* FOOTER */

.footer {
    background: #062134;
    color: white;
    display: table;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.footer .column-title {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.footer > div {
    display: table-row;
}

.footer > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 23%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.footer > div > div:first-child {
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}

.footer > div > div:nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}

.footer > div > div:nth-child(3) {
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 20%;
}

.footer p {
    line-height: 200%;
}

.footer input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #062134;
    /*border: 2px solid white;*/
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
    width: 75%;
    color: white;
    height: 36px;
    text-indent: 10px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #1F3748;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #1F3748;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #1F3748;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
   color: #1F3748;
}

.footer button {
    float: left;
    background: #062134 url(../img/arrow-input-bg.png) 10px 10px no-repeat;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-left: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/*.row-2 p {
    clear: left;
}*/

.footer input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #4D7EC9;
}

.footer input:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em white;
}

.footer button:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

.footer button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.list-of-resources {
    display: table;
}

.list-of-resources > div {
    display: table-row;
}

.list-of-resources > div  > div {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.list-of-resources > div  > div:last-child {
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.list-of-resources a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.list-of-resources a:hover {
    color: tomato;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {

    /* HEADER */

    .header-background {
/*      height: 300px;*/
        padding-top: 0;
    }

    .header-notes {
        padding: 50px 0;
    }

    .header-notes > div {
        width: 70%;
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    .header-background > div:first-child {
        top: 0;
    }

    .header {
        background: #232323;
        color: #B2B2B2;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .header-logo {
        font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
        font-size: 36px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        float: left;
    }

   /*  nav {
        float: initial;
        clear: both;
    }

    nav ul {

        list-style: none;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 15px;
    } */

    /* CONTENT */

    .photos {
        width: 90%;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:900px) {

    .footer > div > div {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 28%;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }

    .footer > div > div:first-child {
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 1%;
    }

    .footer > div > div:nth-child(2) {
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 1%;
    }

    .footer > div > div:nth-child(3) {
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {

    .footer > div > div {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 42%;
    }

    .footer > div > div:last-child {
        clear: both;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }


    #desktop-nav {
        display: none;
    }

    #open-toggle {
        left: auto;
    }


}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {

    .photos ul li {
        padding: 5%;
        width: 40%;
    }

    .photos ul li:nth-child(3n+3) {
        clear: left;
    }

    .photos h3 {
        padding: 15px 0;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .photos p {
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .footer > div > div {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .footer > div > div:nth-child(2) {
        clear: both;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {

    .header-logo {
        font-size: 26px;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    .header-notes > div {
        width: 80%;
        font-size: 26px;
    }

  nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 5px;
    } 

}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="header-background">
        <!-- <div> -->
         <div id="nav">
        <div id="logo">Site Title</div>
        <nav id="desktop-nav">
            <a class="nav-item" href="#1">Github</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#2">About</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#3">Community</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#4">Docs</a>
        </nav>
        <input id="open-toggle" class="nav-toggle" type="text" readonly>
        <input id="close-toggle" class="nav-toggle" type="text" readonly>
        <nav id="mobile-nav">
            <a class="nav-item" href="#4">Docs</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#3">Community</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#2">About</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#1">Github</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
       <!--  </div> -->

       <!--  <div class="header-notes">
            <div><span class="green">/creative</span> one page template</div>
        </div> -->

    </div>
```

and the js field is:--

```
(function(adiachenko) {

    window.addEventListener("load", function() {

        var stuffList = document.querySelectorAll("#stuff-list li");

        if (stuffList.length % 4 === 1) {
            var view = window.innerWidth;

            if (view > 600) {
                [].forEach.call(stuffList, function(stuffMember) {
                    // do whatever
                    stuffMember.style.width = "18%";
                });
            }

            window.onresize = function() {
                view = window.innerWidth;
                changePictureSize(view, stuffList);
            };
        }

        function changePictureSize(view, stuffList) {
            if (view > 600) {
                [].forEach.call(stuffList, function(stuffMember) {
                    // do whatever
                    stuffMember.style.width = "18%";
                });
            } else {
                [].forEach.call(stuffList, function(stuffMember) {
                    // do whatever
                    stuffMember.style.width = null;
                });
            }
        }

    }, false);

}(window.adiachenko = window.adiachenko || {}));
```

**Now I am getting the page is like:-[image: this page]**

**But I want the navigation as like :-[image: this page]**

and this navigation needs to sized as the body of the page..

**navigation.css**

```
#nav {
    position:relative;
    width:620px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

ul#navigation {
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    border-left:1px solid #c4dbe7;
    border-right:1px solid #c4dbe7;
}

ul#navigation li {
    display:inline;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border-top:1px solid #c4dbe7;
    border-bottom:2px solid #c4dbe7;
}

ul#navigation li a {
    padding:10px 25px;
    color:#616161;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    border-left:1px solid #C2C2C2;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    background: #f5f5f5;

    -webkit-transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;   
    -moz-transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;  
    -o-transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;    
    transition:color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;   
}

ul#navigation li a:hover {
    background:#f8f8f8;
    color:#282828;
}

ul#navigation li:hover > a {
    background:#fff;
}

/* Drop-Down Navigation */
ul#navigation li:hover > ul
{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}

ul#navigation ul, ul#navigation ul li ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    visibility:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    width:180px;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #ccc;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; 
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; 
    -o-transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; 
    transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear;     
}

ul#navigation ul {
    top: 43px;
    left: 1px;
}

ul#navigation ul li ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 181px;
}

ul#navigation ul li {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    border:0 none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #c9c9c9;
}

ul#navigation ul li a {
    background:none;
    padding:7px 15px;
    color:#616161;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    border:0 none;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:150px;
}

ul#navigation li a.first {
    border-left: 0 none;
}

ul#navigation li a.last {
    border-right: 0 none;
}
```

but I am failed..where I have to add this field to reach this screen????

Comment: please provide jsfiddle or demo...

Comment: Do you really need all that code to show your problem? Please narrow down to the minimun necessary code.

Comment: please provide jsfiddle with only necessary code

Comment: I have edited the js field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out with the below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/bdd9U/564/

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please explain in brief what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

basic rule of thumb to center align any element is to specify width and margin auto like so

```
.my-class {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help with your issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/4txndpfm/

```
 $('.handle').on('click', function(){
      $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
    });
```

Comment: In mobile,the view is perfect..I have the problem in desktop view..I want to set the navigation in the middle and needs the width of the navigation is same as the content of the body..